# Store concrete generic subclass in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible to store a concrete generic subclass in Realm?

For example:

```
class MyClass<T> : Object{}

class ConcreteMyClass : MyClass<String> {}
```

I know that it is not possible to store **MyClass** in Realm. However, is it somehow possible to store the **ConcreteMyClass**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use concrete generic subclasses for Realm models, you just need to tell Realm to ignore the non-specialized classes:

```
import Cocoa
import RealmSwift

class MyClass<T>: Object {
    dynamic var parentProp = 0
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

class ConcreteMyClass: MyClass<String> {
    dynamic var childProp = 0
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(objectTypes: [ConcreteMyClass.self]))
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(ConcreteMyClass())
}

print(realm.objects(ConcreteMyClass.self))
```

That logs:

```
Results<ConcreteMyClass> (
    [0] ConcreteMyClass {
        parentProp = 0;
        childProp = 0;
    }
)
```

Comment: I was aware that I cannot directly store generics. However ConcreteMyClass is not generic itself, therefore I was hoping this may work somehow.

Comment: Ah, yes that works! Sorry for misunderstanding your question. It was clear, I just misread it. I've rewritten my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: I was trying to implement your solution. However when I try to call ConcreteMyClass() it crashes in the following method:
    @objc private class func getGenericListPropertyNames(object: AnyObject) -> NSArray

Additionally when debugging I found that object is of type MyClass<String> rather than ConcreteMyClass

Comment: It's possible this doesn't fully work. Realm doesn't test this case at all. I suggest you make a feature request to officially support concrete generic mode classes, ideally with a comprehensive list of the things that don't work today.