# Storing a generic subclass in Realm

Tags: swift, generics, realm

I have been trying to abstract a little bit my Realm models, so I wanted to create a superclass model with a generic type. Then, create subclasses for the specific type.

I know Realm does not support storing a generic type. However, my question is:

Is it possible to store a specific defined subclass?

So the idea is to have a superclass:

```
class SuperClass<T: RealmCollectionValue> : Object {

    @objc dynamic var pk: String = ""
    let listProp = List<T>()

    convenience init(pk: String){
        self.init()
        self.pk = pk
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "pk"
    }

}
```

Then implement a specific subclass:

```
class StringSubClass : SuperClass<String> {}
```

Is then the possibility to save in Realm instances of *StringSubClass* (as in fact, it is not a generic)?

From what I have found in this already answered question (which stands it is possible with an accepted answer): [Store concrete generic subclass in Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096243/store-concrete-generic-subclass-in-realm)

You can specify the Realm to ignore the *SuperClass* by defining it to only handle the *StringSubClass*.

However, when trying it in Realm 3.13.1 with:

```
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(objectTypes: [StringSubClass.self]))

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(StringSubClass(pk: "mypk"))
}
```

The following exception is thrown when storing instances of *StringSubClass*

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type 'StringSubClass' is not managed by the Realm. If using a custom `objectClasses` / `objectTypes` array in your configuration, add `StringSubClass` to the list of `objectClasses` / `objectTypes`.'
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the actual code you use to set up your `Realm`. Are you sure you set the configuration correctly?

Comment: @DávidPásztor edited, thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?